# Plot date by month as x-axis on dc.js bubble chart

Tags: javascript, charts, dc.js, crossfilter

Take a moment to examine the bubble chart below. That is an image that I have created in Illustrator. I am now attempting to duplicate the bubble chart with [dc.js](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/).

[image: bubble chart image]

By dissecting the code for the example graphs given on [this page](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/), I have attempted to achieve the above. Here is my code:

```
'use strict'

// define bubble chart and get a handle
var referralsChart = dc.bubbleChart('#referrals-bubble-chart');

// load the csv data
d3.csv("data/data.csv", function (data) {
    /* since its a csv file we need to format the data a bit */
    var dateFormat   = d3.time.format("%d/%m/%Y");
    var numberFormat = d3.format(".2f");

    data.forEach(function (d) {
        d.dd    = dateFormat.parse(d.date);
    });

    // create cross-filter dimensions and groups
    // see the crossfilter api at (https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference) for reference.
    var referralsChartXFilter = crossfilter(data);
    var referralsChartXGroups = referralsChartXFilter.groupAll();

    // dimension by full date
    var dateDimension = referralsChartXFilter.dimension(function (d) {
        return d.dd.getMonth();
    });

    var diagnosisDimension = referralsChartXFilter.dimension(function (d) {
        return d.referredfor;
    });

    // dimension group
    var diagnosisDimensionGroup = diagnosisDimension.group();

    // define the referrals bubble chart attributes
    referralsChart
      .width(700)
      .height(400)
      .transitionDuration(1500) // (optional) define chart transition duration, :default = 750
      .margins({top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 40})
      .dimension(dateDimension)
      //Bubble chart expect the groups are reduced to multiple values which would then be used
      //to generate x, y, and radius for each key (bubble) in the group
      .group(diagnosisDimensionGroup)
      .colors(colorbrewer.RdYlGn[9]) // (optional) define color function or array for bubbles
      .colorDomain([0, 100]) //(optional) define color domain to match your data domain if you want to bind data or color
      //##### Accessors
      //Accessor functions are applied to each value returned by the grouping
      //
      //* `.colorAccessor` The returned value will be mapped to an internal scale to determine a fill color
      //* `.keyAccessor` Identifies the `X` value that will be applied against the `.x()` to identify pixel location
      //* `.valueAccessor` Identifies the `Y` value that will be applied agains the `.y()` to identify pixel location
      //* `.radiusValueAccessor` Identifies the value that will be applied agains the `.r()` determine radius size, by default this maps linearly to [0,100]
      .colorAccessor(function (d) {
        return d.value / 100
      })
      .keyAccessor(function (p) {
        return p.value
      })
      .valueAccessor(function (p) {
        return p.value
      })
      .radiusValueAccessor(function (p) {
        return p.value
      })
      .maxBubbleRelativeSize(0.1)
      .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 5000]))
      .y(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 5000]))
      .r(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 4000]))
      //##### Elastic Scaling
      //`.elasticX` and `.elasticX` determine whether the chart should rescale each axis to fit data.
      //The `.yAxisPadding` and `.xAxisPadding` add padding to data above and below their max values in the same unit domains as the Accessors.
      .elasticY(true)
      .elasticX(true)
      .yAxisPadding(100)
      .xAxisPadding(500)
      .renderHorizontalGridLines(true) // (optional) render horizontal grid lines, :default=false
      .renderVerticalGridLines(true) // (optional) render vertical grid lines, :default=false
      .xAxisLabel('Date') // (optional) render an axis label below the x axis
      .yAxisLabel('Referrals') // (optional) render a vertical axis lable left of the y axis
      //#### Labels and  Titles
      //Labels are displaed on the chart for each bubble. Titles displayed on mouseover.
      .renderLabel(true) // (optional) whether chart should render labels, :default = true
      .label(function (p) {
        return p.key;
      })
      .renderTitle(true) // (optional) whether chart should render titles, :default = false
      .title(function (p) {
          return [p.key,
                 "Referrals: " + numberFormat(p.value.absGain),
                 "Index Gain in Percentage: " + numberFormat(p.value.percentageGain) + "%",
                 "Fluctuation / Index Ratio: " + numberFormat(p.value.fluctuationPercentage) + "%"]
                 .join("\n");
      })
      //#### Customize Axis
      //Set a custom tick format. Note `.yAxis()` returns an axis object, so any additional method chaining applies to the axis, not the chart.
      .yAxis().tickFormat(function (v) {
          return v + "%";
      });

      dc.renderAll();
});
```

The above code works in the sense that I get Bubbles plotted, but the x-axis and y-axis show wrong scales. Here is a screenshot of what I'm getting with the above code:

[image: code bubble chart]

What I'd like is **date by month plotted against the x-axis** (Jan, Feb, Mar ...etc) and on the **y-axis the data range for the referrals**.

The csv data being passed can be [found here](http://pastebin.com/50bjGHaX).

I know that it is the two lines below that I need to edit, but I'm not sure how to pass my data to them.

```
  .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 5000]))
  .y(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 5000]))
  .r(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 4000]))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to set `.x` to a d3.time.scale

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#xxscale---mandatory
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales

It looks like you also want to set `.r` to reflect your data.

Also, you probably don't need to set the `.domain` of your scale objects, since you are using `.elasticX` and `.elasticY`, which will set those automatically.

You may also want the similar `.elasticRadius` to size the bubbles according to the current values.

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#elasticradiusboolean